# Check if a number is between a range using SQL & C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following info:

```
ID   Name                  Range          Checked
1    Jennifer             000-100           0
2    Louis                101-200           0
3    Michael              201-300           0
```

The range are the numbers of the tickets they have, and the checked column are the number of tickets that have been used.

What I want to do is to add +1 to the column Checked when a ticket is used, so I want to check where the ticket belongs. I mean, if I use ticket number 103, I want to add 1 to the column checked in the row number 2. And so on if I use more tickets.

```
ID   Name                  Range          Checked
1    Jennifer             000-100           0
2    Louis                101-200           1
3    Michael              201-300           0
```

So, is there a way to check if the ticket I have submitted is between one of the ranges?

PD.: I know how to check if a number is between two numbers in SQL, and I do also know how to get info from specific rows using C#, what I don't know how to do is to check the entire table to see if the number is between the ranges column.

Comment: It's probably already obvious for you, but you should never store several things into one column, like the range. You should have 2 number columns instead.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll take that in count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Range Values are 3 digits, left() and right() would do the trick without having to find the dash.

**Example**

```
Update YourTable 
   Set Checked=Checked+1
 Where 103 between left(Range,3) and Right(Range,3)

Select * from YourTable
```

**Results**

```
ID  Name        Range     Checked
1   Jennifer    000-100   0
2   Louis       101-200   1
3   Michael     201-300   0
```

> **EDIT - CharIndex() option For Variable Ranges**

```
Update @YourTable 
   Set Checked=Checked+1
 Where 103 between left(Range,charindex('-',Range+'-')-1) and Right(Range,len(Range)-charindex('-',Range+'-'))
```

Comment: Good solution but it answer limit to 3 chars between `-` char. Maybe using `CHARINDEX` function can provider a better solution.

Comment: @FelipeOriani Agreed, hence my top comment.  However, you are correct so I will add the second option with charindex()

Comment: Thanks very much. The first solution applies when is a range of 3 digits an the other one when are more than 3 digits?

Comment: @EdgardeJesusCeballosGarcia correct.  If you only have 3 digits, then the first is more efficient.   However, the second woul support fixed or variable.

Comment: Thanks very much @JohnCappelletti

Comment: @EdgardeJesusCeballosGarcia Happy to help.

Comment: My bad. Since you used a numeric value for `103` it will cause the calculated string values to be converted to integers. ([Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql).) Depending on how the OP provides the target value, e.g. a `Char(3)` parameter, that may not hold true.